# sp_trace_setfilter column datatypes

Tags: trace, sql-server-profiler

Anyone know where i can find a list of the columns for setting the trace filter, i know the system id number as i got this off of MSDN but i need the list with all of the data types but i cant seem to find it anywhere...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-setfilter-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are listed in the BooksOnline on the sp_ trace_setevent page:
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx)